# React and Nodejs

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I've issue in connecting react and express nodejs. On production they are fine together but on dev they are not connected. I've read a lot of articles and none of them worked with me. I'm deploying on heroku. And on production how can I replace local host end points with heroku url.

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "", "../build");
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, "index.html"));
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is up on port " + port);
});
```

for package.json/

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server/server.js",
        "dev": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
```

Comment: is your frontend separate from your backend?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your reactjs and node applications are deployed seperately, you can follow these steps:

**For backend** [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package is very popular, and easy to setup.

1-)  add .env file to the root folder with your environment variables like this:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/
```

Please note that there should be no empty space.

2-) In your main file,  import `dotenv` as soon as possible before reading any variables.

```js
require("dotenv").config();
```

3-) Now you can accesss your variables like this:

```
const dbUrl = process.env.MONGO_URL;
```

4-) put your .env file to the .gitignore file

5-) Specify the version of node.js by adding an [engines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node) section in `package.json` that will be used to run your application on Heroku.

For example:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "10.1"
}
```

6-) After you deploy your node application to the heroku, add your variables using PROD values as described here in [heroku docs](http://%20https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard).

If you created your reactjs app using [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) you can follow these steps:

1-)  Add .env file to the root folder. Your variable names must start with **REACT_APP_**...

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001/api
```

2-) Access your variables like this in your code:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
```

3-) put your .env file to the .gitignore file

4-) After you deploy your reactjs app to the heroku, set prod variables in Config Variables section, as we did for node app.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts for explaining I understand all this. However, my issue is simpler my app now is just presentable it's portfolio so no api so far. my question how can I run front end and back end together on dev and prod? sure there should be change in package.json

Comment: @MahmoudNafea use react environment variables, in your dev .env file put dev values, and for prod use prod values